# Class method returns object from a class that uses methods/properties from the higher class. How?

Tags: php

I'm trying to achieve a simple behavior in my code, but i can't think of a decent way of doing it. Take a look at what i'm trying to do:

```
$db = new Database('mydb');
$db->createTable('sample');

$myTable = $db->getTable('test');
$myTable->insert($data);
$myTable->insert($data);
$myTable->edit('2', $data2);
$myTable->remove('1');
```

getTable is a method of the **Database** class, that returns an object of the **Table** class. The **Table** class has table-operation-specific methods, such as insert, edit and remove. The **Database** class has important methods that **Table** should be able to use, such as exec and query. It also should be able to access properties from **Database**, such as $this->pdo.

Should **Table** extend **Database** or should **Database** have static methods? **Table** uses several methods from **Database**. Is there a design pattern i can use to implement this? A Factory?

Answer (score 3):

Factory doesn't really make sense here as you aren't creating `n` concrete implementations of the same base class (or interface).

I'd probably end up doing something like this (note that this might not actually *run*, providing a concept rather than actual implementation as it's off the top of my head):

```
class Database
{
    private $name;
    public __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function createTable($name)
    {
        $t = new Table($name, $this);
        // sql stuff here
        return $t;
    }

    public function exec($sql)
    {
        // table now has access to this due to the set reference
    }
}

class Table
{
    private $db;
    public function __construct($name, $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's Dependency Injection. Any other way of doing the same thing, without injecting the Database object?

Comment: @vinny: given the requirements stated in your OP, this design makes the most sense (imho), as there are two distinct objects that have different interfaces but the child (table) has a dependency on the parent (database).

Comment: I've been looking at doctrine and, apparently, it uses static methods to do the same thing. Check their getTable method. http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/06-Working-With-Data

Comment: In this case the dependency is kind of warranted, a Table object is dependent on having a Database object to exist within.

Comment: @vinny: That makes sense if you're dealing with a single database instance. If you're (or ever want to ) dealing with multiple database instances, then the `static` method design crumbles in comparison (imho). I've also never really been a fan of static methods when used for anything other than helper-type logic.

Comment: You should use Doctrine 2. If you don't have PHP 5.3, just get it, because 5.2 is starting to become an antique ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that when $db->getTable() creates a new Table object, it passes a reference to itself to the Table class as an argument to new().

The Table class would then perform any exec or query commands against that reference.

Comment: Database is passed as reference to Table through getTable?

Comment: How can i pass that reference?